# Search and replace tags in one object with the values in another object

Tags: javascript, json, templates

I have two json files that I load into a page.  One contains the name and value of the tag.  The other json file contains the html.  I've been stumped for a day googling and trying to replace these tags.

For example:

```
var tags = {
    title: "New Title",
    author: "John Doe"
};

var html = {
    header: "<div id=\"header\"><h1>{{title}}</h1</div>",
    content:  "<div id=\"content\"><h2>{{author}}</h2></div>"
};
```

I lifted this somewhere and I can replace my tags if the html is stored in a string, but I'm having problems getting this to work when the html is in an object.

```
var str = 'The Title is {{title}} and the author is {{author}}.  Proof it will replace multiple tags:  Again the author is {{author}}.';

var content = str.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, function(i, match) {
    return tags[match];
});
```

I need help iterating through all the values in the html object and replacing them with the correct tag values.  Thanks

Comment: can you clarify what your end result should be?

Comment: seems to be working.. what is the problem

Comment: `js` at Question appear to return expected results ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/phfdcstd/1/ ?

Comment: Sorry.  The second part of the example does work as long as I'm replacing the tags in a string (str), but I need to replace each value in the html object.

Comment: I should have made clear that the end result is to replace the values of the html object.  Nothing I've tried works so I didn't post an example iterating through the html values and changing them.

Comment: That looks like a Handlebar Syntax. Can you try passing the second JSON to handlebar compiler as Template and first as data?

Comment: Yes handelbars.  Just trying to keep it lightweight right now and not load another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over each property in `html` object and replace its content

```js
var tags = {
  title: "New Title",
  author: "John Doe"
};

var html = {
  header: "<div id=\"header\"><h1>{{title}}</h1</div>",
  content: "<div id=\"content\"><h2>{{author}}</h2></div>"
};

for (var key in html) {
  if (html.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    html[key] = html[key].replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, function(i, match) {
      return tags[match];
    });
  }
}


content.innerText = JSON.stringify(html, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="content"></pre>
```

Comment: Yes sir!  Thanks a lot.